# Iniciar nodejs no Azure

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

estou com um problema para inciar o nodejs no servidor azure, já configurei tudo certinho e o site já esta no ar, porém estou com um chat em node, utilizando socket.io, veja o código abaixo (index.js):

```
    var express  = require('express');
var app = express(); 
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html'); 
});
   var user = 0;
io.on('connection', function(socket){

     user = user +1;

    console.log(user);
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        user = user -1;
        console.log(' has disconnected from the chat.');
         console.log(user);

    });
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg,nome,cor){
    io.emit('chat message', msg,nome,cor);
  });
});


http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

index.html

```
var socket = io();
         var cor = randomColor();
      $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val(),Cookies.get('name'),cor);
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg,nome,cor){
        $('#messages').append($('<li style="background:'+cor+'">').text(msg));
        $('#messages').append($('<p class="mensagem">').text(nome));

      });
        socket.on("disconnect", function(){
            console.log("client disconnected from server");
        });
```

No azure, no cmd, já instalei os módulos necessarios (socket.io, express)

agora quando digito node index.js ele da uma erro BAD REQUEST.

Alguém poderia ajudar?
Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

No Azure voce nao pode especificar uma porta fixa para rodar a aplicacao. Voce deve checar pela porta nas variaveis de ambiente:

`var port = process.env.port || 3000;
http.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});`